# Parse this JSON response From App Annie in Python

Tags: python, json, request

I am working with the request module within python to grab certain fields within the JSON response.

```
import json
fn = 'download.json'
data = json

response = requests.get('http://api.appannie.com/v1/accounts/1000/apps/mysuperapp/sales?break_down=application+iap&start_date=2013-10-01&end_date=2013-10-02', \
auth=('username', 'password'))

data = response.json() 
print(data)
```

This works in python, as the response is the following:

> {'prev_page': None, 'currency': 'USD', 'next_page': None, 'sales_list': [{'revenue': {'ad': '0.00', 'iap': {'refunds': '0.00', 'sales': '0.00', 'promotions': '0.00'}, 'app': {'refunds': '0.00', 'updates': '0.00', 'downloads': '0.00', 'promotions': '0.00'}}, 
>       'units': {'iap': {'refunds': 0, 'sales': 0, 'promotions': 0}, 'app': {'refunds': 0, 'updates': 0, 'downloads': 2000, 'promotions': 0}}, 'country': 'all', 'date': 'all'}], 'iap_sales': [], 'page_num': 1, 'code': 200, 'page_index': 0}

The question is how do I parse this to get my downloads number within the 'app' block -  namely the "2000" value?

Comment: format your code properly

Comment: data = json??? what should this do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `loads()` method of `json` -

```
import json

response = requests.get('http://api.appannie.com/v1/accounts/1000/apps/mysuperapp/sales?break_down=application+iap&start_date=2013-10-01&end_date=2013-10-02',
                        auth=('username', 'password'))
data = json.loads(response.json()) # data is a dictionary now

sales_list = data.get('sales_list')
for sales in sales_list:
    print sales['revenue']['app']
```

Comment: I tried this (im using python 3.3) and received the following error
TypeError - Expected String or Buffer. 


    def decode(self, s, _w=WHITESPACE.match):
        """Return the Python representation of ``s`` (a ``str`` instance
        containing a JSON document).

        """
        obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())

Comment: Loads needs a json string. Check the data.json() output.

Comment: i not sure if the output is a proper json format. When i simply print(data) i get something that looks like json.

{'page_num': 1, 'code': 200, 'next_page': None, 'iap_sales': [], 'prev_page': None, 'sales_list': [{'revenue': {'iap': {'refunds': '0.00', 'sales': '0.00', 'promotions': '0.00'}, 'app': {'downloads': '0.00', 'refunds': '0.00', 'updates': '0.00', 'promotions': '0.00'}, 'ad': '0.00'}, 'units': {'iap': {'refunds': 0, 'sales': 0, 'promotions': 0}, 'app': {'downloads': '2000'date': 'all'}], 'page_index': 0, 'currency': 'USD'}

Comment: As noted in Tom Ron's answer, response.json() already gives the response in the form of a dictionary, so use of loads() is unneccesary and will cause errors.

Answer (score 2):

After the response.json() data is already a dictionary otherwise response.json() would raise an exception. Therefore you can access it just like any other dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json.loads`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json
import requests

response = requests.get(...)
json_data = json.loads(response.text)
```

This converts a given string into a dictionary which allows you to access your JSON data easily within your code.